# How to make Doctrine result cache work with Redis on Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

Currently I have this on
**framework.cache:**

```
app: cache.adapter.redis
default_redis_provider: redis://localhost
```

**doctrine.orm:**

```
metadata_cache_driver: redis
result_cache_driver: redis
query_cache_driver: redis
```

Sure, it doesn't work, but I have no idea what to even try now. Doing type: pool, pool: cache.app works perfect on Symfony 5/6, but it doesn't do anything on Symfony 3.4, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooo 5 mins after posting I have the answer, everything was in prod/doctrine.yaml...

**doctrine.orm:**

```
metadata_cache_driver:
    type: service
    id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
query_cache_driver:
    type: service
    id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
result_cache_driver:
    type: service
    id: doctrine.result_cache_provider
```

**framework.cache:**

```
app: cache.adapter.redis
system: cache.adapter.redis
default_redis_provider: redis://localhost
```

**services:**

```
doctrine.result_cache_provider:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
doctrine.system_cache_provider:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'
```

**Bonus edit**. How to provide custom namespace:

Create a pool service **services:doctrine.cache_pool:**

```
doctrine.cache_pool:
    parent: 'cache.app'
    tags:
        - { name: 'cache.pool', namespace: 'app' }
```

Then use it in a definition for doctrine.system_cache_provider '@doctrine.system_cache_pool' => '@doctrine.cache_pool'.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and maybe will be helpful for you too:

config/packages/cache.yaml

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        prefix_seed: '%env(resolve:APP_NAME)%'
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: '%env(resolve:REDIS_DSN)%'
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: redis_adapter
                provider: redis_provider
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
```

config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
    # ...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
```

Comment: Yeah, with this one I'm getting `Unrecognized option "pool" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.metadata_cache_driver"` in 3.4, but such configuration works great in 5/6.